# Connection error Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to test in Real time database and I can't create any node in the database. What am I doing wrong? I think that problem can be the conection of android studio with the Firebase, but looks like that all the conection is ok. I would appreciate your help.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button:Button = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit)
        val etValue:EditText = findViewById(R.id.etValue)

        val rootRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        val demoRef: DatabaseReference = rootRef.child("demo")

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val value: String = etValue.text.toString()

            demoRef.setValue(value)
        }
    }
}
```

*Build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebaseexample.firebaseexample"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
            google()  // Google's Maven repository
            mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

        }
        dependencies {

            // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'


        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
}
```

Comment: We can see what you enter in the text box, so I recommend trying something like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("test").set(true);` too. If you do that, does the `true` value show up in the database console? If not, are there any relevant warning/errors written to the logcat when the `set` runs?

Comment: Good morning, thank you very much for answering my question, I have entered the line of code that you have suggested (I have changed its "set" to setValue, "set" does not recognize it) and nothing appears in the realtime database. In my Logcat, choosing Firebase, I don't see any errors and in the case of "Run only selected application" I only see a "Flag x" error...which doesn't have much to do with the problem. I don't understand why it doesn't connect. If there is anything else I can do to make you see my mistake, tell me...it's a bit frustrating. hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself! the problem is the android studio emulator, I have installed on a physical device and the database updates the data. Do I have to remove the emulator from the system and reinstall it? I will check